# PHP slice off numbers after 4 non zero numbers in decimal

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is :

```
0.000000023455676554434 -> 0.0000002345
0.00000000000000000000002656565-> 0.00000000000000000000002656
0.012345 -> 0.01234
```

Code till now :

```
bcdiv(rtrim(sprintf('%.20f', $decimal), '0'),1,13);
```

The current code removes scientific notation, and trims any zeros towards the end if any, and cuts the decimals after 13 decimal points. but if the decimal is something like `0.023123123235435346` it would still show 13 decimal points while I am looking to get only `0.02312`.

Any help wold be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to cut off after 4 non-zero numbers?
Or want you 4 numbers after first non-zero number
How should that be treated?
0.00600045678

Answer (score 0):

You can use base 10 log to get the number of zeros between the point and the first digit. This would do what you want:

```
$decimal = "0.00000000000000000000002656565";
echo bcdiv($decimal, 1, -1*floor(log($decimal, 10))-1+4);
```

> Output: 0.00000000000000000000002656

Comment: Calculating with float internally can lead to incorrect results: "0.0099999999999999999999" -> 0.00999

Answer (score 0):

I think preg_replace is also very easy to do. The value should be available as strings and not as float.

```
$trimValue = preg_replace('~(\d*\.0*[1-9]{4}).*~','$1',$value);
```

If you want 4 numbers after first non-zero number use this:

```
$trimValue = preg_replace('~(\d*\.0*[1-9]\d{3}).*~','$1',$value);
```

A complete test (First variant):

```
$data = [
  '0.000000023455676554434', // -> 0.0000002345
  '0.00000000000000000000002656565', //-> 0.00000000000000000000002656
  '0.012345', // -> 0.01234
  '0.023123123235435346', //0.02312
  '0.00565',
];

$trimValues = [];
foreach($data as $value){
  $trimValues[] = preg_replace('~(\d*\.0*[1-9]{4}).*~','$1',$value);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_export($trimValues);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '0.00000002345',
  1 => '0.00000000000000000000002656',
  2 => '0.01234',
  3 => '0.02312',
  4 => '0.00565',
)
```